# Django Web Development

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am a beginner in python and django and im practicing making a website for selling stuff. I am in the part where I am supposed to edit a card from bootstrap with the attributes from my models.py that is also in the views.py as a function.

This is the html:
(the 'base.html' is the starting template from bootstrap)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %}
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <div class="row">
        {% for product in products_dict %}
         <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.image_url }}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ product.price }}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the result that i get:

[As you can see the cards just keep on stacking to the right and decrease in size, it does not come down.]

Can anyone help me with this? Please tell if I need to share more info on this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXQXr.jpg

Comment: Is there supposed to be an extra image attached or a link showing the result you get?

Comment: the image didnt show. i have now put the link

Comment: Have you checked to see if the image url's that you are passing it returns an image when you access that url? the alt tag is showed instead when the image can't be found at that url.

Comment: i think that might be the problem, i may have not entered the correct url. I'll try it again

Comment: i can now make the images show. however i did not get the card positions that I wanted